# How to get a database to show in a pagerAdapter Fragment?

Tags: android, cursor, android-cursorloader

This is code from my Fragment, at present it's not loading anything from the database, which definitely exists.  I've been revising it as per kind Edmund's guidance, passing in mCursor, with the whole database table, to mCursorAdapter in the hope that onLoadFinished the adapter would update printing the database to screen.  But onLoadFinished() nothing happens :/.  Help!

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.quotes.obama.obamaquotes.data.PetContract.PetEntry;
import com.quotes.obama.obamaquotes.data.PetDbHelper;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

//import android.content.CursorLoader;

/**
 * Created by Sam on 30/10/2016.
 */
public class AllQuotesFragment extends Fragment implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> { //}, android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Object> {

    /** Identifier for the pet data loader */
    private static final int PET_LOADER = 0;

    /** Adapter for the ListView */
    PetCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;

    /** so know when we have the database ready for display */
    static Boolean databaseLoaderComplete = false;

    public AllQuotesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @return A new instance of fragment GameFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static AllQuotesFragment newInstance() {
        AllQuotesFragment fragment = new AllQuotesFragment();
        //Bundle args = new Bundle();
        //args.putString(TITLE, pageTitle);
        return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quotes_all, container, false);
        // inflate fragment_game into "container",

        // Find the ListView which will be populated with the pet data
        ListView petListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Find and set empty view on the ListView, so that it only shows when the list has 0 items.
        View emptyView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        petListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);

        /* as per Edmund
        * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517872/how-to-wait-for-cursorloader-to-complete/40530754?noredirect=1#comment68332991_40530754 */

        // To access our database, we instantiate our subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper
        // and pass the context, which is the current activity.
        PetDbHelper mDbHelper = new PetDbHelper(getContext());

        // Create and/or open a database to read from it
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        // Perform this raw SQL query "SELECT * FROM pets"
        // to get a Cursor that contains all rows from the pets table.
        Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + PetEntry.TABLE_NAME, null);


        // Setup an Adapter to create a list item for each row of pet data in the Cursor.
        // There is no pet data yet (until the loader finishes) so pass in null for the Cursor.
        mCursorAdapter = new PetCursorAdapter(getContext(), mCursor); // was null
        petListView.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);

        // TODO Setup the item click listener?
        Log.w(TAG, "about to initLoader");
        // Kick off the loader, need activity to get Context

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(PET_LOADER, null, this);

        Log.w(TAG, "All Quotes UI created, returning ");
        return rootView;

    }
    @Override
    public android.support.v4.content.Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        // Define a projection that specifies the columns from the table we care about.
        Log.i(TAG, "creating a loader");

        String[] projection = {
                PetEntry._ID,
                PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME,
                PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_BREED };


        // This loader will execute the ContentProvider's query method on a background thread
        return new CursorLoader(getContext(),   // Parent activity context
                PetEntry.CONTENT_URI,   // Provider content URI to query
                projection,             // Columns to include in the resulting Cursor
                null,                   // No selection clause
                null,                   // No selection arguments
                null);                  // Default sort order

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(android.support.v4.content.Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        // Update {@link PetCursorAdapter} with this new cursor containing updated pet data
        mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
        Log.i(TAG, "database updated");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(android.support.v4.content.Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        // Callback called when the data needs to be deleted
        mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
        Log.i(TAG, "database reset");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fragment "winning" shouldn't be a problem as onLoadFinished() should load the cursor data after the fragment is displayed.

Replace:

```
getActivity().getLoaderManager()
```

with:

```
getLoaderManager()
```

and make sure you're using the support LoaderManager with a support Fragment.

Also, pass the cursor rather than null into the adapter constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the natural logic, use the method [onLoadFinished()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html#onLoadFinished(android.support.v4.content.Loader%3CD%3E,%20D))

Comment: I've tried changing the flag there, and it never gets reached.  I put a Log in the while loop above and it just spews the Log in an infinite loop, I think the while loop must somehow be blocking the loader from completing.

Is there a different way of waiting for the loader to finish?  Without while loop?

Answer (score 0):

[Edited: This answer now includes suggestions made in the comments below, so there is no need to read the comments. ]

The fragment "winning" shouldn't be a problem as onLoadFinished() should load the cursor data after the fragment is displayed.

Remove the while loop to allow onCreateView() to return - I'm assuming the code shown is in onCreateView().

It's also worth replacing:

```
getActivity().getLoaderManager()
```

with:

```
getLoaderManager()
```

and make sure you're using the support LoaderManager with a support Fragment.
Also, pass the cursor rather than null into the adapter constructor.

Comment: There is no need to suspend execution until the loader returns.  Just display the previous data or the empty view, ideally with a 'loading' icon or similar.

Comment: Hey Edmund, thanks for your time.  You are right, I'm returning from onCreateView.  If I don't wait for the loader to return, then the rootView returns, and the PagerAdapter draws the fragment without any data, and it doesn't get updated with the data when the cursor loader finishes.  2. If I get rid of getActivity() then it won't let me pass context (this), as an argument in initLoader.  I would love your help, I can't have the app open with an empty page, and require users to swipe to another tab, and then back to get a view refreshed with the database.  Perhaps I should post more code?

Comment: Is onLoadFinished() being called?  I suspect it is.  As you're in a fragment, it makes sense to call the fragment loader manager, rather than the activity loader manager (though I've never tried it that way).  In onActivityCreated() in the fragment, it should be possible to call getLoaderManager().initLoader(PET_LOADER, savedInstanceState, this);

Comment: ... because your fragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>.  This should also be possible in onCreateView().  When you say "it won't let me pass context (this) as an argument in initLoader", how does it prevent you, is there an error message?

Comment: Also, are you saying that the data IS displayed when the user swipes to another tab, then back again?

Comment: When omitting getActivity() an IDE lint? error says: Wrong 3rd argument type. Found: 'com.quotes.obama.obamaquotes.AllQuotesFragment', required: 'android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<java.lang.Object>'.  Why is using getActivity() a problem?  2.  onLoadFinished() is called, however by the time it's called onCreateView has returned, and the adapter has thrown up an empty dataset screen.  I need a way of either waiting for onLoadFinished in onCreateView, or a way of forcing a refresh when I hit onLoadFinished.

Comment: 3.  Yes data is displayed when I swipe back again.  I've setup the pagerAdapter to have all the tabs displaying the same database fragment, at least during development, and the database is there for them, because onLoadFinished has been hit - I presume.

Comment: 1. Using getActivity() may not be a problem, but better to use the fragment's loader manager in case it is.  Check whether you are using the support classes for Fragment and LoaderManager.  Using the non-support LoaderManager with a support fragment will give the error you describe.  2. The display of the empty dataset screen looks OK, it is how it is designed to work, and many apps do this.  You see the existing data until the new data has been fetched, then (if it is all working) the new data is displayed.  In other words, the way you wait for onLoadFinished is by just waiting.

Comment: 3. Swiping away and back may cause the data to be re-fetched and, as you say, it is now there.  Is the data displayed if you wait just as long but without swiping?

Comment: I just noticed your comment "There is no pet data yet (until the loader finishes) so pass in null for the Cursor."  The adapter will allow the displayed data to be updated when the cursor data changes, so although there is no data at that point, the cursor still needs to be passed to the adapter.

Comment: Hey Edmund, thanks so much for your help.  I've created a cursor which hands the adapter the full Database table, (a bit more than I need to display).  However it's not display it.  I've updated the code above, any idea where the problem might be?  Or common problems at this stage?  I need to learn more I think.

Comment: Hi Samuel, the code you've shown all looks good.  The CursorAdapter is working, as the data is shown when you swipe away and back.  For the CursorLoader, you need a ContentProvider to provide all rows of the database when given the URI PetEntry.CONTENT_URI, declared in the manifest.  If you don't have this, do some reading up on ContentProviders.  If you do, try debugging the code to see what's happening, and if that doesn't help, post the code here.

Comment: Yay!  I'd forgotten to insert into the database, and had uninstalled and reinstalled the app at some point.  So yes it's working.  A THOUSAND thank yous, if you post an answer I'll mark it correct.  I think the key change was importing the right library (this happens too frequently), and secondly passing a Cursor into into the CursorAdapter, instead of null, which made sure it updates.  Thanks again :)

Comment: Great news! These comments are part of an original answer I made, which I've now updated to include my other suggestions which were useful.  Are you able to mark my original answer as accepted?

Comment: No comments I can't mark, if you hit the blue Answer Question box at the very bottom, then copy and paste the comment, then it's clearer to people what the remedy was, and I can mark it solved.  Still vibrating, onward.

Comment: OK cool, just thought you might like the site's kudos points.  Thanks so much for your repeated attention and assistance, you've been awesome. :)